# Greasemonkey renaming texts from array only works once

Tags: arrays, function, greasemonkey

just discovered greasemonkey and played a bit.
I tested this line to change text content of a website

```
document.body.innerHTML= document.body.innerHTML.replace("someone","funny");
```

and it worked just fine.
I wanted to replace some more texts on that website but did not want to copy & paste that again and again so I wrote a little function like:

```
function a(s,d){document.body.innerHTML= document.body.innerHTML.replace(s,d);}
```

calling it that way:

```
a("test","success");
```

Also without problems. But then I wanted to call that function multiple times; like:

```
a("test","success");
a("some","thing");
```

but my script only executed the first function .. ?

I tried another way, using an array .. sourcecode is like this:

```
var array = [];
array.push("john")
array.push("jane")
array.push("foo")
array.push("bar")
b(array);

function b(array)
{
for(var i = 0; i<(array.length-1); i=i+2)
{
   document.body.innerHTML= document.body.innerHTML.replace(array[i],array[i+1])
}
}
```

but again .. only executes once ..

Am I doing something wrong ?

Because using
document.body.innerHTML= document.body.innerHTML.replace("foo","bar")
document.body.innerHTML= document.body.innerHTML.replace("some","one")

works just fine :E

Answer (score -1):

> for(var i = 0; i<(array.length-1); i=i+2)

Might be part of your problem...

The array length is 4.... you start counting at 0 which means that you only go to 3 on the list (I think), and then i=i+2 means that you are only processing every other one (I think)..

try

```
for(var i = 0; i<(array.length-1); i=i++)
```

or

```
for(var i = 0; i<(array.length); i=i++)
```

Wait.......... when it executes does it show the first array value or the last?  It may be looping too fast to see all of them, since you are replacing one with the next